# Why am I unable to import a module in my working directory?

Tags: python

So I have a bunch of code that I'm trying to run.

In one part, I've set my working directory and executed code that is stored there.

```
cd /Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/object_detection_cats/object_detection/

python3 export_inference_graph.py \
    --input_type image_tensor \
    --pipeline_config_path data/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config \
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix data/model.ckpt-997 \
    --output_directory object_detection_graph
```

However, this is producing this error.

```
from object_detection import exporter
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-0bc5d13491d6>", line 1, in <module>
    from object_detection import exporter

ImportError: cannot import name 'exporter'
```

This makes no sense because the exporter file is in the working directory.

[image: contents in my directory]

Why is the import command not working?

I went and tried to import it in Spyder by just setting the os.chdir and then importing, but that also causes an error.

```
os.chdir('/Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/object_detection_cats/object_detection')

import exporter  ### THIS WORKS!!!!!

from object_detection import exporter
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-0bc5d13491d6>", line 1, in <module>
    from object_detection import exporter

ImportError: cannot import name 'exporter'
```

Comment: do you have a file called object_detection.py ?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes, that file has all the files in the image I linked above

Answer (score 0):

The working directory is inside the `object_detection` directory. For `import object_detection` to work, you'd need to be in the *parent* directory, `/Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/object_detection_cats`. So either:

1. Work out of the parent directory (for old versions of Python, you may need to make an empty `__init__.py` in `object_detection`, but modern versions use implicit namespace packages so `__init__.py` shouldn't be needed), or
2. Change the import to just `import exporter` (which is a module in the working directory in its own right).